# Maximum of norm inducted by inner product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

I want to choose such two norms $\Vert\cdot\Vert_a, \; \Vert\cdot\Vert_b$ for which:

$$\Vert\cdot\Vert_c := \max\{\Vert\cdot\Vert_a, \; \Vert\cdot\Vert_b\}$$

Is a norm inducted by inner product.

**My work so far**

According to [Maximum of two norms is norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369816/maximum-of-two-norms-is-norm) I'm asured that my object is well defined. Norm is inducted by inner product when the following formula is satisfied:

$$\Vert x+y \Vert^2 + \Vert x-y \Vert^2 = 2(\Vert x \Vert^2 + \Vert y \Vert^2)$$

Let's define $A := (x_1, y_1)$, $B:= (x_2, y_2)$ and rewrite the formula above:

$$\Vert A+B\Vert_c^2 + \Vert A-B \Vert_c^2 = 2(\Vert A\Vert_c^2 + \Vert B \Vert_c^2)$$

$$\Vert (x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)\Vert_c^2 + \Vert (x_1-x_2, y_1-y_2)\Vert_c^2 = 2(\Vert (x_1, y_1)\Vert_c^2+\Vert (x_2, y_2)\Vert_c^2)$$

$$ \max{\{\Vert x_1 + x_2 \Vert_a, \Vert y_1 + y_2 \Vert_b\}}^2 + \max{\{\Vert x_1 - x_2 \Vert_a, \Vert y_1 - y_2 \Vert_b\}}^2 = 2( \max{\{\Vert x_1 \Vert_a, \Vert y_1 \Vert_b\}}^2 + \max{\{\Vert x_2 \Vert_a, \Vert y_2 \Vert_b\}}^2)$$

And here I wasnt sure which norms $a, b$ to chose. I tried some combinations $\mathbb{l}_1$ with supremum but it doesn't give me more than just bizzare looking expressions.

Could you please help me findin some norms $a$ and $b$ for which parallelogram law holds ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different idea. The unit ball of the $\|\cdot\|_c$ norm is equal to the
intersection of the unit balls of the $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ norms. Now choose two norms such that the intersection of their unit balls is the Euclidean unit ball.

Here is one on $\mathbb R^2$:
$$
\|(x_1,x_2)\|_a:= \begin{cases} \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} & \text{if }x_1x_2 \ge 0\\\max(|x_1|,|x_2|) & \text{if }x_1x_2 < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Define $\|(x_1,x_2)\|_b:=\|(-x_1,x_2)\|_a$. Since $\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)\le\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$, we have $\max(\|(x_1,x_2)\|_a,\|(x_1,x_2)\|_b) = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$.

Comment: Hey @daw thank you very much for your answer! I just have one question related to it. How do you know that $\max(\|(x_1,x_2)\|_a,\|(x_1,x_2)\|_b) = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ ? i.e. it's just assuming that $x_1x_2 \ge 0$. Besides you defined norm $b$ as let's use word 'reversed' norm $a$ i.e. $\|(x_1,x_2)\|_b:=\|(x_2,x_1)\|_a$. However it doesn't make any difference right ? Due to the fact that $\|(x_2,x_1)\|_a = \|(x_1,x_2)\|_a$

Comment: I understand you're saying that for such defined norms $\Vert \cdot \Vert_a$, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_b$ one of them will be $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ and second one $\max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$. Due to fact that $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} \ge \max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$ - maximum of those (so norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_c$) will be always $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$. The only thing which is not make fully sense for me it's that one of those norms will be in format $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ and second one in maximum. In my opinion norms $a$ and $b$ are equal.

Comment: just, you are right. Have to flip the sign of one coordinate for the $b$-norm.

Comment: Perfect! Now it makes sense! Maybe the last question to be as formal as possible. How do you know that such defined norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_a$ is a norm ?

Comment: :) Tried triangle inequality on paper. At the end only one case is important, should work with some case distinctions on signs.